# Alternative to toast when using widgets in Android 12, as toast is now clipped

Tags: android

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have created an application with a widget. The widget is a simple button that executes a bit of code and then returns a message to the user via a toast. However, I notice that in Android 12 toasts are now truncated to two lines and often the message is longer. I don't like snack bars, but I appreciate that my main app can be converted to use them, but what should I use to do the same job via a widget?

The snack bars require a layout view to work, but I can't figure out how to remove that from the widget code. You could use an alert dialog, but even though the code compiles, it just doesn't seem to show up. I'm open to suggestions here... What is the best way to display a message on the home screen when a widget is pressed? Is there a way to tell the app not to truncate the toast or else what is the best alternative?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.